# Articles on MSE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, article, collectives

I noted the "Articles" tab here on my MSE [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile):

[image: "Articles" link and tab]

Does this mean that articles are coming to MSE as well (which wouldn't really serve a purpose IMHO), or is this a bug and should this only be visible on SO?

Comment: No one mentioned it to us... D:

Comment: Are articles coming on all SE sites?

Comment: Where is the article about articles?

Comment: The use of the [tag:article] tag seems correct (spelling (characters chosen), and usage consistent with that on MSO) ***but*** its [earliest usage **here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) is entirely different; so you're nominated to switch the other dozen posts to a new tag @JourneymanGeek (as Luuk doing it would bump).

Comment: Me doing it would bump too. If retagging is needed it needs to be brought up formally

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! This is a bug, and we're on it. Should be hidden fairly soon. We'll answer and update this meta post whenever it's fixed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: If you wanted, it'd be possible to use the Merge tool to rename the existing tag without bumping all the question, then retag this question to recreate the tag under this name (which would bump this question). Though if that's going to be done, it should probably be agreed upon by the community first, as you say.

Comment: Also the merge tool is scary 

Comment: The tab is there on all network sites, not just MSE

Comment: @JD-Stack, also while the Articles "tab" is simply blank (which is not so bad) the Articles (apparently, but not) "help" link (above the tab, "View all questions, answers, and **articles**") simply sends us [404 on every site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=articles) with the [exception of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=articles); of course.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks for pinging me. Yeah, this should be solved as well when we implement the general fix for the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this bug. The "Articles" tab and the link (above the tab) should now only be visible on SO.

Comment: Welcome to MSE and thanks for fixing this :)